# Entity null - Linq to SQL

Tags: linq-to-sql, constructor, null

I need some help...

I have my entity that i have create manually.

```
public class Project()
{
 public Project Data {get;set;}
 public string ProjectID { get; set; }
 public string AreaID { get; set; }
 public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

Where property "Project" is the the table created by SQLmetal.

I have also created my class, with SQLmetal, wish there have there own entity. 
Now i trying to parse between them in the constructor like:

```
public Project()
{
 ProjectID = Data.ProjectID;
 AreaID = Data.AreaID;
 Country = Data.Country;
}
```

But when I use

```
projects.Select(p => new Project { Data = p });
```

the Data property in the constructor is null.

Any idea why? and how will I solve this the better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because the initializer

```
var x = new Project { Data = p };
```

is equivalent to

```
var x = new Project();
x.Data = p;
```

The `Data` property is set AFTER the constructor.

You can solve it by creating a constructor that takes Data as a parameter

```
public Project(Data data)
{
    this.Data = Data;
    ProjectID = Data.ProjectID;
    AreaID = Data.AreaID;
    Country = Data.Country;
}
```

and call the constructor

```
projects.Select(p => new Project(p));
```